# scan very large database for malware

Tags: mysql, search, malware

I have a very large database with over 20 years of customer data in it.  We had some malicious form responses over the weekend that had integrated malware that infected the two people who just viewed the data's browsers.  One of those people deleted all of the suspicious responses they could find and now they are both cleaning up their computers/browsers/etc.

I checked the htaccess file and all 1200+ rewriterule's seem to be accurate, but hard to tell.  Now I'd like to do some general searching of the database, but don't know a relatively easy way.  We have 110 tables.  Any suggestions or recommendations?  Also, what are things I should check for besides iframe?

Comment: hi i post answer, i am emphasizing php, if you are not using php, but your server supports it, please check it anyway.

Comment: also  i forgot to mention - check user upload directory as well, no matter "all files are well checked" - usually those are world writable and file might come from other source.

Comment: exactly how do you get malware into a database? if you're talking about javascript or something, then your system is obviously vulnerable to XSS attacks and you've got a bigger problem...

Comment: You're vulnerable to XSS attacks.  See http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html and https://www.cert.org/historical/tech_tips/malicious_code_mitigation.cfm.  And you might want to work (swiftly) to properly encode, decode, and escape.

Comment: If you're getting burned by malware that easily, you have a **serious** security problem on your computers. It's normally almost impossible to contract this stuff with a casual click, you really have to go out of your way to download and install things. Scanning a database for malicious URLs is basically impossible, these change constantly, so secure systems that have access to it. Using Chrome will employ Google's malware link blocking service, which is better than nothing. Other more aggressive methods might be required.

Answer (score 1):

dump the database and check text file with the dump.

check all writable files with extention php. we had similar situation where we used html extention and only affected files were some test php files.

if is php, check all files for base64_decode, gzdecode, exec and similar functions...

check google webmaster tools for exact snipped. however do not forget that almost always snippet shown in webmastertools is 'altered' e.g. you have mallitious snipped that sends redirect, that sends redirect and final snipped is shown in google.

chech image directory for uploaded php files with strange names, such something.jpg..spaces...php

Comment: did this info helped? if you post update for the progress I might edit

Answer (score 1):

If you have phpMyAdmin, open it up and use the search feature to look for the following terms:

- eval
- base64_decode
- gzinflate
- shell_exec
- GLOBALS
- error_reporting(0)

Their presence could indicate a malware infection.

See these for more info: [1](https://www.fixrunner.com/how-to-scan-wordpress-for-malware/), [2](https://www.sitelock.com/blog/how-to-check-for-malware/)

Also you can use a Wordpress plugin to scan for malware. My favourite is Wordfence but there are [others](https://www.fixrunner.com/wordpress-malware-removal-plugins/).

Comment: I found malicious occurences of `base64_decode` in a database, thank you.